# How to sort all rows according to a specific label?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Consider of having a google sheet with 10 columns (10 users) and 10 rows.

```
column A : Users' first name
Column B:  Users' Last name
Column C: Users' id ( which is a number)
Column D to J:  User specific information ( each row for one user)
```

My Question:
I usually have to import those above 3 columns (Name,last name and user ID) manually. So, when new users have registered, assume I have 15 new users (so in total 10 (old users) + 15(new users) = 25 users). These 25 users are sorted in my database. When I copy and pasted them in my sheet, all information of old users (from column D to J) are useless. So, I was thinking of a way that I can create a label for each row, and match that label to user id. So, every time I add new users, it looks for user Id and if it matches with label, place that row in front of it, something so-called sorting by label.

UPDATE:
Link to my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/108RNqgl_yHVdU6B46S7J2h7oQZmiaJ1EM2Q5vrPeCiY/edit?usp=sharing

I hope I could transfer my concern clearly.

Comment: @player0 I've updated my question with a spreadsheet. Thanks

Comment: If your database holds all the data (old and new) why not just clear the sheet and populate it with the data from the database? I can see that, for example, `C22` and `C25` have the same ID, assuming the db always has all new & old, why not clear the sheet and add all the values?